# subprocess call of ffmpeg returns negative value

Tags: python, ffmpeg

Here is the original command line call that works at shell:

```
ffmpeg -i /Users/abc/Desktop/Test/Full_Mov.mov -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/System/Library/Fonts/Keyboard.ttf: text='SCENE BLAH BLAH - %{frame_num}': start_number=1: x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=white: fontsize=20: box=1: boxcolor=black: boxborderw=5","format=yuv420p" -f segment -segment_frames 123 -reset_timestamps 1 -c:a copy -map 0 "/Users/abc/Desktop/Test/%03d_test40.mov"
```

Getting a negative value when trying to run ffmpeg via subprocess, causing it to fail and not process.  I've even tried dumbing down the call to just run ffmpeg by itself with no arguments, and it still returns a negative value.

```
import subprocess
ffmpeg = "/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg"
source = "/Users/abc/Desktop/Test/Full_Mov.mov"
destination = "/Users/abc/Desktop/Test/%03d_test40.mov"
cmd = "%s -i %s -vf \"drawtext=fontfile=/System/Library/Fonts/Keyboard.ttf: text='SCENE BLAH BLAH - %%{frame_num}': start_number=1: x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=black: fontsize=20: box=1: boxcolor=white: boxborderw=5\",\"format=yuv420p\" -f segment -segment_frames 123 -reset_timestamps 1 -c:a copy -map 0 \"%s\"" % (ffmpeg, source, destination)
log("ffmpeg cmd: %s" % cmd)
log(subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True))
```

When running full command:

```
CalledProcessError: Command '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i /Users/abc/Desktop/Full_Mov.mov -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/System/Library/Fonts/Keyboard.ttf: text='SCENE BLAH BLAH - %{frame_num}': start_number=1: x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=black: fontsize=20: box=1: boxcolor=white: boxborderw=5","format=yuv420p" -f segment -segment_frames 318 -reset_timestamps 1 -c:a copy -map 0 "/Users/abc/Desktop/Test/%03d.tmp.mov"' returned non-zero exit status -8
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
```

When running just ffmpeg no arguments:

```
CalledProcessError: Command '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg' returned non-zero exit status 1
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
```

Latest output with suggested changes below:

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg', '-i', '/Users/szaharak/Desktop/Flix_Test/ep888_sq66_main_mov_2019_05_20_14_15.mov', '-vf', 'drawtext=fontfile=/System/Library/Fonts/Keyboard.ttf:', 'text=SCENE BLAH BLAH - %%{frame_num}:', 'start_number=1:', 'x=(w-tw)/2:', 'y=h-(2*lh):', 'fontcolor=black:', 'fontsize=20:', 'box=1:', 'boxcolor=white:', 'boxborderw=5', 'format=yuv420p', '-f', 'segment', '-segment_frames', '123', '-reset_timestamps', '1', '-c:a', 'copy', '-map', '0', '/Users/szaharak/Desktop/Flix_Test/%03d_test40.mov']' returned non-zero exit status 1

[NULL @ 0x7f88c3012200] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'text=SCENE BLAH BLAH - %%{frame_num}:'
text=SCENE BLAH BLAH - %%{frame_num}:: Invalid argument
```

And here is latest...

```
    >>> rc = subprocess.check_call(cmd)
ffmpeg version N-93891-ge1839283bc-tessus  https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
  configuration: --cc=/usr/bin/clang --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --extra-version=tessus --enable-avisynth --enable-fontconfig --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-version3 --pkg-config-flags=--static --disable-ffplay

  libavutil      56. 28.100 / 56. 28.100
  libavcodec     58. 52.102 / 58. 52.102
  libavformat    58. 27.103 / 58. 27.103
  libavdevice    58.  7.100 / 58.  7.100
  libavfilter     7. 53.101 /  7. 53.101
  libswscale      5.  4.101 /  5.  4.101
  libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
  libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/Users/szaharak/Desktop/Flix_Test/ep888_sq66_main_mov_2019_05_20_14_15.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2019-05-14T17:58:24.000000Z
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.audio.gain: 1.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.audio.treble: 0.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.audio.bass: 0.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.audio.balance: 0.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.audio.pitchshift: 0.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.audio.mute: 
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.visual.brightness: 0.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.visual.color: 1.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.visual.tint: 0.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.visual.contrast: 1.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.player.version: 7.6.6 (7.6.6)
    com.apple.quicktime.version: 7.7.3 (2943.14) 0x7738000 (Mac OS X, 10.11.6, 15G22010)
  Duration: 00:01:12.67, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 23379 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mjpeg (Baseline) (jpeg / 0x6765706A), yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1280x720 [SAR 72:72 DAR 16:9], 21838 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24k tbn, 24k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-05-14T17:58:24.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Video Media Handler
      encoder         : Photo - JPEG
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16be (twos / 0x736F7774), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-05-14T17:58:24.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
[NULL @ 0x7f8ddc8ce200] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'text=SCENE BLAH BLAH - %{frame_num}: start_number=1: x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=black: fontsize=20: box=1: boxcolor=white: boxborderw=5: format=yuv420p'
text=SCENE BLAH BLAH - %{frame_num}: start_number=1: x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=black: fontsize=20: box=1: boxcolor=white: boxborderw=5: format=yuv420p: Invalid argument
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 190, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg', '-i', '/Users/szaharak/Desktop/Flix_Test/ep888_sq66_main_mov_2019_05_20_14_15.mov', '-vf', 'drawtext=fontfile=/System/Library/Fonts/Keyboard.ttf:', 'text=SCENE BLAH BLAH - %{frame_num}: start_number=1: x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=black: fontsize=20: box=1: boxcolor=white: boxborderw=5: format=yuv420p', '-f', 'segment', '-segment_frames', '123', '-reset_timestamps', '1', '-c:a', 'copy', '-map', '0', '/Users/szaharak/Desktop/Flix_Test/%03d_test40.mov']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Comment: you should try with just `check_call` to see what is the output. `check_output` isn't going to print anything in the case of wrong return code. You can also get rid of `shell=True` and pass the arguments as a list, not a string.

Comment: This is interesting because the entire command above works on the command line.  I will relook it and also try check_call/post results.

Comment: my bad quotes are matched. But you arguments as list is the way. strings are too risky. And ffmpeg arguments are notoriously hard to tune/understand too...

Comment: This seems more tedious as a list.  I am literally separating everything into its own argument delimited by a space?  It goes on forever.

Comment: did you check with `check_call` to see if ffmpeg outputs an intelligible message?

Comment: @Zak44, the list is *much* safer; without it, you need to worry about malicious names. If someone gives you an input file that contains `$(rm -rf ~)` in its name, you *really* don't want that name processed by a shell. And trivial approaches like putting quotes before and after substituted values don't close that vulnerability; `$(rm -rf ~)'$(rm -rf ~)'` is likewise a possible filename on common systems.

Comment: @Zak44, ...it's generally fairly safe to expand variables in shell scripts (at least in double-quotes to suppress string-splitting and globbing) because there are only very few steps in the parsing process left after parameter expansion takes place in a shell; but when you substitute values into strings that are then passed to a shell as code, the parsing starts from the very beginning, and you have much more security exposure.

Answer (score 1):

`ffmpeg` command line is tricky as there are a lot of special arguments and mistakes are sometimes difficult to understand, the program sometimes interprets/discards wrong arguments, resulting in cryptic error messages.

Another difficulty is using `check_output`. You don't really need to do this, and if the program fails you won't have any output at all.

I would try the following (that I could not test), which is to:

- drop `shell=True`
- pass a *list* of arguments instead of composing the string yourself. It allows to forget about the quoting/escaping. You don't need to format the command, source & destination since they're standalone arguments:
- Don't log, just print with `check_call`.
  As a bonus, you'll get the output in real-time, instead of in the end...

note that I have removed the single quotes in `"text=SCENE BLAH BLAH - %{frame_num}:,` too and unescaped the `%` char.

like this:

```
cmd = [ffmpeg,"-i",source,"-vf",
      "drawtext=fontfile=/System/Library/Fonts/Keyboard.ttf:",
      "text=SCENE BLAH BLAH - %{frame_num}: start_number=1: x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=black: fontsize=20: box=1: boxcolor=white: boxborderw=5: format=yuv420p",
      "-f","segment","-segment_frames","123",
       "-reset_timestamps","1","-c:a","copy","-map","0",destination] 
log("ffmpeg cmd: %s" % cmd)
rc = subprocess.check_call(cmd)
if rc:
    raise Exception("ffmpeg failed")
```

for the case of `ffmpeg`, you could migrate to [ffmpeg python module](https://pypi.org/project/ffmpeg-python/). Could save some argument parsing trouble too.

Comment: Sorry not having much luck... still same.  The entire drawtext filter was a string in itself and I think splitting it up this way makes it invalid.

Comment: oh probably a typo in your filter in the first place. I joined back all the args with ":" in the end: `"text=SCENE BLAH BLAH - %{frame_num}: start_number=1: x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=black: fontsize=20: box=1: boxcolor=white: boxborderw=5: format=yuv420p"` check update.

Comment: No luck same thing.  I put the actual shell command that works perfectly up top of the question.  Notice that certain sections have to be padded with quotes.  This is why splitting apart like this is more hassle than it seems... I understand what you are trying to accomplish, but it just seems to not be working when I split it up.  Frustrating.

Comment: with my last change you cannot have this error: `[NULL @ 0x7f88c3012200] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'text=SCENE BLAH BLAH - %%{frame_num}:' text=SCENE BLAH BLAH - %%{frame_num}:: Invalid argument` because %% aren't doubled now. Can you edit for the error?

Comment: See above for latest

Comment: I believe the "format=yuv420p" needs to be part of the filter, but separated by a comma?

Comment: okay, try with a comma then, and tell me. I'll edit if it works